# Converting little endian to int

Tags: c#

First of all, I think this question is not C# independent. But can also be used in other languages like C.

---

I'm now trying to parse a file format which stores integers in 4 bytes little-endian format.
TBH, I don't know how the little-endian format nor big-endian format works.

But I need to convert them into an usable int variable.

For example,
02 00 00 00 = 2

So far, I have this code to convert the first 2 bytes: (I used FileStream.Read to store the raw datas into a buffer variable)

```
        int num = ((buffer[5] << 8) + buffer[4]);
```

But it will only convert the first two bytes. (02 00 in the example, not 02 00 00 00)

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
int GetBigEndianIntegerFromByteArray(byte[] data, int startIndex) {
    return (data[startIndex] << 24)
         | (data[startIndex + 1] << 16)
         | (data[startIndex + 2] << 8)
         | data[startIndex + 3];
}

int GetLittleEndianIntegerFromByteArray(byte[] data, int startIndex) {
    return (data[startIndex + 3] << 24)
         | (data[startIndex + 2] << 16)
         | (data[startIndex + 1] << 8)
         | data[startIndex];
}
```

Comment: `(data[startIndex + 3] << 24) | (data[startIndex + 2] << 16)` - Why does this work?

Comment: @alex what do you mean, why does what part of that work? Hoping I can clarify this

Comment: @Goku Just hoping for a bit more in the way of an explanation

Comment: @alex, How about an example:
If we have have a byte array of 2 bytes {15, 255}. If we go 
(data[0] << 8) | data[1] then the machine will translate this to:
0000111100000000 | 0000000011111111 which is equal to 0000111111111111 or 4095 dec

Answer (score 8):

Using built-in methods:

```
byte[] data = { 2, 0, 0, 0 };
Array.Reverse(data);
int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
```

On the other side of the spectrum, using optimised unsafe code:

```
public static unsafe void SwapInts(int[] data) {
  int cnt = data.Length;
  fixed (int* d = data) {
    byte* p = (byte*)d;
    while (cnt-- > 0) {
      byte a = *p;
      p++;
      byte b = *p;
      *p = *(p + 1);
      p++;
      *p = b;
      p++;
      *(p - 3) = *p;
      *p = a;
      p++;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You can use the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to check if the computer is using little endian or big endian internally, so that you can make the code portable.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library has some code for handling endian-ness.

Comment: 404 ... never post link only answers ;-)

Comment: New link is https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/

Answer (score 2):

my universal solution from little endian to int is this:

```
public static int GetLittleEndianIntegerFromByteArray(byte[] data)
{
    int length = data.Length;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result |= data[i] << i * 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what do you think happens if they pass in data.Length > 4? ints are usually 32 bits long....

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the function in much simpler syntax:

```
        private int GetFromBigIndian(byte[] array)
    {
        int value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            value |= (array[i] << i * 8);
        }

        return value;
    }
```