# Method difference between languages (Python->C#)

Tags: c#, python, unpack, binaryreader

I am trying to reproduce a sequence of code from a Python program in C#. In Python I have:

```
element1, element2 = struct.unpack('!hh', data[2:6])
```

The above statement unpacks from a "substring" of data in short-short (network byte order) format. The values resulted (element1,element2) are: **96** and **16**

My attempt in C# is:

```
byte[] bytesOfInterval = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data.Substring (2, 4));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytesOfInterval)) {
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
        Logger.Trace (reader.ReadInt16().ToString());
        Logger.Trace (reader.ReadInt16().ToString());
    }
}
```

It outputs: **24576** and **4096** .

As you can see the output from the Python program is slightly different from the C# one. To verify the "substrings" (input), I've encoded them in hex format to see if there is any difference. They were both equal to **00600010**, hence, the input is the same the output is different. ***Why?***

Notes:

- *Substring(2,4)* is the equivalent of the "sliced" string in Python *[2:6]*
- Visit http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters for format characters (for pack/unpack in Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem try this for example

```
Int16 x1 = 4096;  
var x2 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(x1);
```

x2 will be **16** (same for **24576** => **96**)

So you can use `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` method.

Comment: Don't use `HostToNetworkOrder` for general-purpose endian-swapping, especially for doing the opposite of what it says (converting network order to host order)… That's what [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. See the linked docs for sample code.

Comment: Or just see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620885/c-sharp-binary-reader-in-big-endian) for how to wrap it all up nicely. (I'd prefer to pass the endianness to the constructor, and swap if it's `!= BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, rather than always swapping in one class and never in another… but it's good sample code.)