# Use a BinaryReader on a MemoryStream in C#

Tags: c#, memorystream, binaryreader

I'm using a memory reader to read a file and put it in a MemoryStream. The MemoryStream is populated, and I'm trying to read with the BinaryReader because the endianness of the file change, so I use a Binary reader that can detect the endianness.

When I use BinaryReader.Read or BinaryReader.ReadString or BinaryReader.ReadByte, it reads the correct data, but when I use ReadInt16 or the other like that, I don't get the correct data. Is it possible to use those, I made a mistake, or should I make something to use Read() instead?

The code:

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  object[] binMakerNoteObj = exif.findTag(37500).data;
  byte[] binMakerNote = binMakerNoteObj.Cast<byte>().ToArray();
  ms.Write(binMakerNote, 0, binMakerNote.Length);
  ms.Position = 0;

  // Read the header
  string t = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
        t += fileStream.ReadChar();
  version = fileStream.ReadUInt16();
  unknow = fileStream.ReadUInt16();
  byteOrder = fileStream.ReadUInt16();
```

Comment: have you tried readallbytes?

Comment: Well I can use Read but I just want to use ReadUint16, I don't think readAllbtes will be useful.

Comment: If the file stores its data as big-endian, then ReadInt16 or ReadUint16 won't work correctly because they assume little-endian.

Comment: I know, that's why I want to use Readint16, it will do the work but it have nothing to do with the endian, just to function returning two different things

Comment: ReadInt16 (actually, any of the Read* methods that reads more than one byte) reads in little-endian order. You will need to swap the bytes in order to get the correct values.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620885/c-sharp-binary-reader-in-big-endian might help you.

Comment: That's not the problème, the readint16 read the correct data when on a filestreal but not a memorystream.

Comment: The first caracter are "System.byte[]" if i read the char with readint16 and I transform tem to char, si tjere is a problem somewhere.