# C# getting 1st 2 integers out of a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter

I have a byte[] like this

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

this byte[] may have values like this:

```
buffer = {0, 0, 0, 106, 0, 0, 0, 11, 64, 33, 50, 32, 32, 32, ....}
```

I am trying to get first 8 bytes, that is:

`0,0,0,106`

`0,0,0,11`

, and convert these into integers which is 106 and 11.

I can safely assume that first 8 bytes always represent 2 integers like in example above, these are 106 and 11 and that they take form of 4 bytes with 1st 3 being 0's like above.

**Both are 4 byte signed integers in Hi-Lo order**

How do I do that in C#?

Comment: @GiladGreen - only when the triple zeroes are also guaranteed.

Comment: Are we assuming these are 4-byte integers, most significant bytes first?

Comment: .net has the `BinaryReader` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @DanielA.White - I would expect the same endiannes as BitConverter.

Comment: @DanielA.White, BinaryReader reads integers in little-endian format. OP specifically mentions that the integer octets/bytes are in Hi-Lo order (big-endian order)

Comment: @elgonzo i linked this in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620885/c-sharp-binary-reader-in-big-endian

Comment: Yeah, just saw your answer now. My apologies for my superfluous comment :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple DIY function:

```
int BytesToInt32(byte[] buff, int offset)
{
    return (buff[offset + 0] << 24)
         + (buff[offset + 1] << 16)
         + (buff[offset + 2] << 8)
         + (buff[offset + 3]);
}
```

and then:

```
buffer = {0, 0, 0, 106, 0, 0, 0, 11, 64, 33, 50, 32, 32, 32, ....};
int a = BytesToInt32(buffer, 0);
int b = BytesToInt32(buffer, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to access indices 3 and 7:

```cs
int first = buffer[3];
int second = buffer[7];
```

There is an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`.

This is possible due to the following:

> I can safely assume that [...] they take form of 4 bytes with **1st 3 being 0's**

Therefore you only need the last byte of each 4-byte integer.

Comment: @user6f6e65 yes, what did I miss?

Comment: He wants the first 4 bytes to be combined to make a 32-bit int. *Not* casting the bytes

Comment: @user6f6e65 Since the first three bytes will always be zero, only the last byte is needed from each integer.

Comment: it was ironic as i hadn't read the question thoroughly. lmao. you get my upvote

Comment: @user6f6e65 no worries haha

Comment: "with 1st 3 being 0's" was added later.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert your `byte[]` into a `MemoryStream` (or leave it as a `Stream`). Then use a `BinaryReader` as appropriate. If the endianness isn't correct: [C# - Binary reader in Big Endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620885/c-sharp-binary-reader-in-big-endian)

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int BytesToInt(byte[] array, int startIndex){
    int toReturn = 0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + 4; i++)
    {
        toReturn = toReturn << 8;
        toReturn = toReturn + array[i];
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the convert class.

```
int myint1 = Convert.ToInt32(buffer[someIndex1]);
int myint2 = Convert.ToInt32(buffer[someIndex2]);
```

As others mentioned, if it's guaranteed that index 4 and index 7 has the non-zero bytes then you can just plug it in straight.