# 32 bit binary sequence to integer conversion

Tags: binary, cpu-architecture, endianness, binary-data

Let's say I have a 32 bit binary sequence, like

```
0100 0001 0111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Given that the smallest possible memory allocation is a byte, how can I convert this to 32 bit (signed and unsigned) integer? LITTLE ENDIAN format is used.

Comment: You mean you have a 32-*byte* sequence of ASCII digits?  If you already have a sequence of 32 bits packed together, it already is a 32-bit binary integer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out the answers here: [Converting little endian to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674160/converting-little-endian-to-int)

But you could also use:

```
 Convert.ToInt32(yourString,2)
```

(The 2 is the base of input for the string and for binary that is 2)

Which uses little endian by default (as far as I know). Assuming that the spaces in your string are only for readability and not really in the actual string to convert.