# Get size of the File Allocation Table in an exFAT disk using C#

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, fat, exfat

I'm writing a program that copies the FAT to a file (and restores it). I'm using `CreateFile` to open a drive letter as a file, `SetFilePointerEx` to seek to 0 position, `ReadFile` to read the contents of the drive, and `WriteFile` to write to the drive.

Using this strategy I can basically copy the entire drive. However, how should I know where to start and when to stop? Basically, what I want to know is the location of the beginning and the end of File Allocation Table in an exFAT disk.

Here's the code that I use to run the backup for the first 4 GB of data:

```
    private static void RunBackup(string driveLetter)
    {
        IntPtr handle = CreateFile(
            string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}:", driveLetter),
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.Read,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (FileMode)OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero);
    
        // Set offset
        uint chunks = 100;
        uint bufferSize = 512 * chunks;
        long pt = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        SetFilePointerEx(
            handle,
            0,
            ref pt,
            0);
    
        long oneGB = 1073741824;
        var backupSize = oneGB * 4;
        var loops = backupSize / bufferSize;
    
        Console.WriteLine($"Expecting {loops:N0} loops.");
    
        uint read = 0;
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"D:\\fat.backup")))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                ReadFile(
                    handle,
                    buffer,
                    bufferSize,
                    ref read,
                    IntPtr.Zero);
    
                writer.Write(buffer);
                writer.Flush();
    
                Console.Write($"\rLoop: {i:N0}");
            }
    
            writer.Close();
        }
    
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [exFAT specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification) is a good start.

In §2 ‘Volume structure’, we have a table:

> | Sub-region Name | Offset (sector) | Size (sectors) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | First FAT | FatOffset | FatLength |
> | Second FAT | FatOffset + FatLength | FatLength × (NumberOfFats − 1) |

`FatOffset`, `FatLength` and `NumberOfFats` are fields of the boot sector, as described in §3.1 ‘Main and Backup Boot Sector Sub-regions’:

> | Field Name | Offset (byte) | Size (bytes) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | FatOffset | 80 | 4 |
> | FatLength | 84 | 4 |
> | NumberOfFats | 110 | 1 |

The values are in sector units, so you will have to multiply them by the sector size before calling `SetFilePointerEx`.  The sector size can be obtained from the [`DeviceIoControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) call [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntdddisk/ni-ntdddisk-ioctl_disk_get_drive_geometry_ex); the returned [`DISK_GEOMETRY_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntdddisk/ns-ntdddisk-_disk_geometry_ex) structure contains a `Geometry.BytesPerSector` (nested) field.  The `FatOffset` and `FatLength` values are little endian, so you will have to decode them with a function like:

```
private static uint ReadLE32(byte[] data, uint offset)
{
    return (data[offset + 3] << 24)
         | (data[offset + 2] << 16)
         | (data[offset + 1] << 8)
         | data[offset];
}
```

It’s also typical to read the whole boot sector to extract information from it, not individual fields.  Remember also that any of the Windows API calls may return an error: if you worry about reliability, you should be checking return values and convert them into exceptions as necessary.

Putting it all together: you open the disk as before, read its boot sector, discover the offset and size of the FAT, then seek to the FAT and read it off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check my edit. I posted some of my code. Based on that, please explain a little more in detail what I should do. Is the current method to open the drive OK? Should I only read 2 bytes and compute the result?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori You don’t check for errors, which I assume may be returned as return values by the native Windows APIs (unless C# is somehow converting them into exceptions).

Comment: @AlirezaNoori As for how to read the values from the boot sector, see <https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674160/>. Best to read the whole boot sector, then decode the values at the specified offsets of the boot sector. Then seek to the first sector of the FAT (having multiplied `FatOffset` by the sector size) and read it off.

Comment: Sorry. Now I'm more confused. When I open the disk using `CreateFile` and `"\\\\.\\J:"` as path, is the first byte, the start of boot sector? So if I seek to byte number 80 and read 4 bytes, it would be `FatOffset` and the next 4 bytes would be `FatLength`. Am I correct?

Comment: So basically I should call `SetFilePointerEx` like this `SetFilePointerEx(handle, 80, ref pt,0);` and read 8 bytes. The first 4 would be `FatOffset` and the next 4 bytes would be `FatLength`

Comment: And if I read these two numbers, where should I get the number of FATs? Should I use the windows properties for the drive or can I read them somewhere else? Could you please give me the exact formula. This is a little too sensitive for me to experiment. Thanks